# Setup MongoDB in VNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some issues using MongoDB in the a VNext project

Link to github with code https://github.com/Mech0z/MagicDraftStatistics/tree/NewFeatures

If I use this package

> mongocsharpdriver

Which is now obsolete, I get

> Warning   'MongoClientExtensions.GetServer(MongoClient)' is obsolete: 'Use the new API instead.'

and 6 of these

> Error The type or namespace name 'MongoServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And I am not sure if I need to change something in my project.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "mongocsharpdriver": "2.0.0.0-beta2"
```

The wierd thing is that the GUI do not show any errors, only the Error list
[image]

If I change to the new official driver then I cant get the same code to work, and the documentation for the driver dont seem to have changed http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/

But I get 
[image]

Comment: I haven't tried messing with vNext, but perhaps you should include the dependencies of the driver as well. MongoDB.Driver, MongoDB.Driver.Core, and MongoDB.Bson. Maybe listing all of them in your dependencies list will resolve the problem.  If you are starting a new project, I'd also drop the mongocsharpdriver dependency and just use the 3 I listed here. There is no documentation because it's in beta. Docs are being written right now.

Comment: Didnt work, but removed "aspnetcore50": { } and now it works, really dont understand how those things are related, but looked at https://github.com/spboyer/mongomvc and that worked and did not have that reference

Comment: I can't get this to work with either version of the driver on either of the two machines I've tried it on. It seems extremely unreliable so far. I'm glad it worked for you though!

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but I wanted to add more info based on my last comment. I had a company Nuget package source that was failing auth (SILENTLY! YAY!) and preventing KPM from doing its job. Once I removed it the proposed solution worked. VStudio doesn't do a good job of surfacing this error, I didn't figure it out until I ran KPM from the command line.

Comment: Do you know a link to a guide on how to use KPM?

Comment: This problem exists in 2013 Vs as well . The version of driver I use is 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason it works when I remove "aspnetcore50": { } from frameworks. Not sure what implications that will have

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
],
"packExclude": [
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "mongocsharpdriver": "1.8.3"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { }
}
}
```

Comment: Finally, did you got any problems removing aspnetcore50 ? Because I'm having the same problem as you

Comment: @Tareck117 No solution, just a workaround https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball9000 I made a normal class library project (Not VNext class library) for my repositories and a models class library so both the repository project and the foosball project can see it