# Mongocsharpdriver not working with ASP:NET Core 5.0 (vNext)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

So I'm getting my feet wet with ASP.NET 5.0, and want to start off using MongoDB.

I've done this in several projects, just not in vNext before.

I add the "mongocsharpdriver" to the project.json and everything seems fine, but when I compile, I get a bunch of errors about mongo and ASP.NET 5 Core (The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found ...). No compile errors for regular ASP.NET 5, just for Core. Is mongocsharpdriver not support for Core? It doesn't seem to have any dependencies, but of course, I don't expect the mongo team to have it compile against Core just yet.

I've looked at this question [Setup MongoDB in VNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663047/setup-mongodb-in-vnext), but it doesn't really help me, as I want to keep the project compiling for Core too!

Any input?

Comment: What is your question? The MongoDB driver only has DLL's for net45 in it's nuget package but you already said that, so you kind answered your own question?

Comment: If somebody else has had same issues, I would like to know that. As I've written, it works (compiles) with ASP.NET 5 - just not ASP.NET 5 Core. Or, if there's a fix, apart from removing "aspnetcore50"  from the project.json file, I would like to know

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 5 with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484761/asp-net-5-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not have support for CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`). See the question I referenced as duplicate.

The only solution for now is to not compile for CoreCLR or, on that framework, use another DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MongoDB with visual studio 2015 RC (published 30 april 2015).

remove 1 line from project.json;

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }, // don't forget to remove ','
    "dnxcore50": { } // remove this line
}
```

now you can build your solution without any error or warning.

[image]
[image]