# How to add reference to other project in ASP.NET 5 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In a Visual Studio 2015 solution I have a folder structure as follows:

```
 -src
    -Project.Models
       (...)
       -MyModel.cs
    -Project.Web
       (...)
       -Controllers
         -MyControllers.cs
       -Dependencies
       -project.json
```

Where `Project.Web` is a ASP.NET 5 Web API project and `Project.Models` a ASP.NET 5 Class Library.

Now I want to use `MyModel` of `Project.Models` in `MyController` of `Project.Web`. To do this I need to reference the Models project from the Web project. I cannot get this to work here. The `using Project.Models` statement keeps highlighting the `Models` part in red because the assembly reference cannot be found.

[image: The problem visualized]

What I tried:

- The usual "Add reference" in combination with using statement
- Creating a NuGet package of `Project.Models` (by specifying "Compile on built" in properties), adding the NuGet package to a local repository and referencing it in project.json.

Both things do not seem to work also after restarting Visual Studio.

Can someone explain to me how to accomplish referencing the `Project.Models` from `Project.Web`?

*/Edit Include project.json:*

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Xml": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "MongoDB.Driver": "2.0.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

*And global.json*

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "runtime": "coreclr",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using .NET Core. When I changed my frameworks entry in the project.json file to use

```
"dnx451": { }
```

instead of

```
"dnxcore50": { }
```

the references were included again (the red of the image became black). Seems like .NET core does not (yet?) support all packages.

Comment: thats ok if you only care about running on the desktop version of the framework dnx451. But dnxcore50 is the new lightweight cross platform framework that most of us do want to use. This problem could probably be solved a different way, if you put the full project.json in your question then someone might see the problem with your references.

Comment: @JoeAudette Okay I'l add it.

Comment: ok it is because the MongoDB.Driver does not currently support dnxcore50 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736372/mongocsharpdriver-not-working-with-aspnet-core-5-0-vnext so I guess you will have to remove dnxcore50 but later when a compatible mongo driver is available you could add it back